# Drawing Radial Gradients in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How do I draw a radial gradient button in BlackBerry? I found "[Drawing Radial Gradients](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/Drawing-Radial-Gradients/td-p/594931)" on the BlackBerry support forums. All I am able to implement on my own is a linear gradient.

Comment: You found a link that has code for a radial gradient, which is what you are asking for. In what way does that solution fall short?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue I have tried that code, im getting different color not gradient. But i need exact Radial gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  Drawing linear gradients on field backgrounds is easy.  Drawing radial gradients on field backgrounds is harder.  Doing it on a button is harder still.

First of all, the example you link to does indeed look really bad.  The biggest problem with that code is that it uses `Graphics.drawArc()` to construct the gradient out of concentric circles (lines).  This is not at all smooth.

The biggest improvement you need to make over that is to use `Graphics.fillArc()` instead, which will look much smoother (although there may be a performance impact to this ...).

Your question didn't say anything about how you wanted the button to look when *focused*, or whether the corners needed to be rounded.  That's where some of the difficulty comes in.

If you just extend the RIM `ButtonField` class, you'll probably have trouble with the default drawing for focus, and edge effects.  It's probably necessary to directly extend the base `Field` class in a new, written-from-scratch, button field.  I wouldn't necessarily recommend that you do all this yourself, since buttons require focus handling, click handling, etc.  You should probably start with something like the [BaseButtonField](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BaseButtonField.java) from the BlackBerry AdvancedUI open source library.

I have prototyped this for you, using that class as a base.  (so, you'll need to download and include that source file in your project if you use this).

I created a GradientButtonField subclass:

```
   private class GradientButtonField extends BaseButtonField {

      private int startR;
      private int startG;
      private int startB;

      private int endR;
      private int endG;
      private int endB;

      /** the maximum distance from the field's center, in pixels */
      private double rMax = -1.0;

      private int width;
      private int height;

      private String label;
      private int fontColor;

      /**
       * Create a gradient button field
       * @param startColor the integer Color code to use at the button center
       * @param endColor the integer Color code to use at the button edges
       * @param label the text to show on the button
       * @param fontColor color for label text
       */
      public GradientButtonField (int startColor, int endColor, String label, int fontColor) {         
         // record start and end color R/G/B components, to 
         //  make intermediate math easier
         startR = (startColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
         startG = (startColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
         startB = startColor & 0xFF;
         endR = (endColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
         endG = (endColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
         endB = endColor & 0xFF;
         this.label = label;
         this.fontColor = fontColor;
      }

      public String getLabel() {
         return label;
      }

      protected void layout(int w, int h) {        
         width = Math.min(Display.getWidth(), w);
         height = Math.min(Display.getHeight(), h);
         if (rMax < 0.0) {
            rMax = Math.sqrt((width * width)/4.0 + (height * height)/4.0);
         }
         setExtent(width, height);  
      }

      private int getColor(double scale, boolean highlighted) {
         int r = (int)(scale * (endR - startR)) + startR;
         int g = (int)(scale * (endG - startG)) + startG;
         int b = (int)(scale * (endB - startB)) + startB;

         if (highlighted) {
            // just brighten the color up a bit
            r = (int)Math.min(255, r * 1.5);
            g = (int)Math.min(255, g * 1.5);
            b = (int)Math.min(255, b * 1.5);
         }
         return (65536 * r + 256 * g + b);         
      }

      protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         int oldColor = graphics.getColor();

         // we must loop from the outer edge, in, to draw
         //  concentric circles of decreasing radius, and 
         //  changing color
         for (int radius = (int)rMax; radius >= 0; radius--) {
            double scale = ((double)radius) / rMax;
            boolean focused = (getVisualState() == Field.VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS);
            graphics.setColor(getColor(scale, focused));
            int x = width / 2 - radius;
            int y = height / 2 - radius;
            graphics.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 360);           
         }

         String text = getLabel();
         graphics.setColor(fontColor);
         graphics.drawText(text, 
               (width - getFont().getAdvance(text)) / 2,
               (height - getFont().getHeight()) / 2);

         // reset graphics object
         graphics.setColor(oldColor);
      }         
   }
```

To use this, the `Manager` that contains the button will need to constrain the button's size in its `sublayout()` implementation.  Or, you can edit my `GradientButtonField` class to hardcode a certain size (via `getPreferredWidth()`, `layout()`, etc.), or whatever you want.

```
  final Field button1 = new GradientButtonField(Color.DARKGRAY, Color.BLUE, 
        "Click Me!", Color.WHITE);
  final Field button2 =  new GradientButtonField(Color.DARKGRAY, Color.BLUE, 
        "Click Me, Too!", Color.WHITE);

  Manager mgr = new Manager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL) {

     public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return Display.getHeight();
     }
     public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
     }

     protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());

        layoutChild(button1, 160, 80);
        setPositionChild(button1, 20, 50);

        layoutChild(button2, 120, 60);
        setPositionChild(button2, 20, 150);
     }
  };

  button1.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
     public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        Dialog.alert("clicked!");               
     }
  });

  mgr.add(button1);
  mgr.add(button2);
  add(mgr);
```

I did not round the corners, as that's a bit of work.  Depending on what kind of backgrounds you're putting these buttons on, it might be easiest to create a PNG *mask* image (in your favorite drawing program), which is mostly transparent, and then just has filled corners that mask off the corners of the gradient below it.  Then, use `Graphics.drawBitmap()` in the `paint()` method above, **after** you've drawn the radial gradient.

For focus highlighting, I just put in some simple code to brighten the colors when the button is focused.  Again, you didn't say what you wanted for that, so I just did something simple.

Here's the result of the code above.  The bottom button is focused:

[image]